# Move region return empty region

Tags: image-processing, halcon

I have a region and I want to move it to the right by 590 columns with the move_region operator, but the operator returns me an empty region

```
union1 (Regions, Regions) 
move_region(Regions, RegionMoved, 0, 590)
connection(RegionMoved, ConnectedRegions)
```

the region is
[image]
area = 15653
center = 783.516, 148.932

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate HALCON region from contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194866/generate-halcon-region-from-contour)